# Should I clear InAppBrowser cache and session cache after OAuth 2.0 authentication?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, cordova-plugins, openid-connect

The title really says it all, but of course will provide some details around the question.

**Background**

My Ionic3 application is using OAuth 2.0 for authentication. Here is the flow:

1. User clicks login
2. An InAppBrowser webview is opened, directing them to an OpenID Connect login portal page.
3. Upon successful login, a redirect url is called and an auth_code is sent along with it.
4. The app (using an event listener) sees this url with an auth_code, and force closes the InAppBrowser and grabs the auth_code
5. The app then sends that auth_code to a server application to get the token set (access_token, refresh_token etc.) and verifies/validates they have not been spoofed or tampered with.
6. Upon successful validation the token set and user info is sent back to the app and stored in local storage and user can enter app.

I can then keep users authenticated as long as the session has not expired, otherwise I can use the refresh_token to authenticate again.

My question comes in at **step 2**.  What ***I'm not sure of*** is whether or not I ***should*** clear browser cache and/or clear session cache of the InAppBrowser.

**Am I opening my app up to any vulnerabilities or threats if I do not clear the browser cache and session cache?**

If so I can just use access/refresh token for continuous authentication, but I am curious and can't find much info on this scenario.

Example Clearing:

```
webview = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(openIdUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes');
webview.addEventListener('loadstart', (event) => {
      if(event.url.inclues('redirect://?code')) {
        // Grab auth_code in event.url
        ...
        webview.removeEventListener('exit', () => {})
        webview.close();
        // Send auth_code to my server
        ...
      }
    });
```

Example Not Clearing:

```
webview = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(openIdUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,clearcache=no,clearsessioncache=no');
webview.addEventListener('loadstart', (event) => {
      if(event.url.inclues('redirect://?code')) {
        // Grab auth_code in event.url
        ...
        webview.removeEventListener('exit', () => {})
        webview.close();
        // Send auth_code to my server
        ...
      }
    });
```

[InAppBrowser Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)

**clearcache:** set to *yes* to have the browser's cookie cache cleared before the new window is opened

**clearsessioncache:** set to *yes* to have the session cookie cache cleared before the new window is opened

Any definitive answers / knowledge is greatly appreciated. Very new to this space.

Comment: I have exact smilar flow..when i use clearcache as no..i get oauth access is denied error